# using cmake, build a visual studio project with dependencies, being able to debug also into the dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a C++ project source code with several dependencies (C++ packages, compiled libs and source).
I need to create a CMake file which will generate the Visual Studio solution and projects files in such a way that if I put a break point in one of the dependencies source code, the execution of the main project in debug mode would break and debug at that break point in the dependency.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

[EDIT]

If I use the packages, with the provided ...config.cmake files, the source files are not included in the generated project.

If I generate the MS projects individually and use `include_external_msproject` to put them together in a solution, I have the source code, but it is executed from somewhere else (binaries), so my breakpoints are ignored.

On the other hand, there is overlap from duplicated targets, like `DOCUMENTATION` for example, which come from each dependency, if I want to use `add_subdirectory` to add the deps to the main project

Comment: Normally it just works with nothing special so I don't know of any suggestion. You may have to explain your problem in greater detail.

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, I updated my question. What would be the normal approach? Thanks.

Comment: I have never used include_external_msproject. At work and at home I use independent CMake and QMake projects and vcpkg where I build the dependencies first. Then I am using CMake as the the project generator for my own application that  needs the other dependencies.  My advice is to check the log for symbols not loaded when you start the debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the dependencies so that they implement unique target names for documentation, but if built individually to create the original named target: DOCUMENTATION.

```
    doxygen_add_docs(DOCUMENTATION_${PROJECT_NAME}
                     doc
                     src/component
                    )
    
    if (NOT (TARGET DOCUMENTATION))
        add_custom_target(DOCUMENTATION COMMENT "workaround for multi-dependencies project")
        add_dependencies(DOCUMENTATION DOCUMENTATION_${PROJECT_NAME})
    endif()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a CMakeLists.txt with the appropriate compile options. To do that, you can set the following CMake values in the CMakeLists.txt file :
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "your-msvc-debug-options")` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_DEBUG_FLAGS "your-msvc-debug-options")`. You may also use `add_compile_options()` which will set values for all your project (dependencies included if you build them with CMake)